# Why when I update my app it doesn't change anything?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play, smartphone

Ok, here's the problem:
I'm working on an app for android that is already on the store. The problem is that I had to make a few changes and after updating the version, produced the build and sign it, I uploaded it on Play Store and after a few minute I could update it on my phone.
Problem is that, other than version, everything remined the same as before.

One of the changes that I use as a test is that after over 10 update there still is an hardcoded value that was removed.

`IDE: Android Studio 11.0.15; Framework: Cordova 8.1.2; build automation tool: Gradle 7.1.1;` 
This is a change example (login.page.html):

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title position="center">
      Goccia Mobile 0.63
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Here I just changed the version value (0.0.75) (config.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="goccia.mobile.app" version="0.0.75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Goccia Mobile</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="30.0.3" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Same story here (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="75" android:versionName="0.0.75" package="goccia.mobile.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

When I look on my phone, after the update, in login page is still writed 0.0.36 (an old version).

If you need more info, just ask and sorry for my poor english skill.

Thanks for the help.

I tried many different thing:

- Changing android studio version;
- Creating .aab file from scratch;
- Reinstalling gradle;
- Changing the pc I was working on;
- Putting version number much higher than the previous;
- Manually setting gradle properties;

Comment: send more data; gradle, manifest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.